# Extracting a wild card characters into the table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to extract all records in product table wherein PRODUCT starts with letter N and save it in a table named "List of N - Products"

I've tried with `Select * from product where PRODUCTS like = 'N%' ;`

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why a table rather than a view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT e.col
  INTO [ListofN-Products]
  FROM yourTable e
  WHERE e.col LIKE 'N%'

  SELECT * 
  FROM [ListofN-Products]
```

Hopw it Help you !

Comment: Not sure why you would want to drop the table at the end?

Comment: Oh Sorry. this Query I Create temporary table for test this Query I'll edit my query now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a simple `INSERT` statement like this:

```
--Assuming all the column names are same in both tables
INSERT INTO [ListOfN-Products] 
SELECT p.*
FROM Product p
WHERE p.PRODUCTS like 'N%'
```

Also, like @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested, why not create a view instead of a table. Unlike tables, views gets automatically updated when new records are inserted in underlying tables.

```
CREATE VIEW [ListOfN-Products]
AS
SELECT p.*
FROM Product p
WHERE p.PRODUCTS LIKE 'N%'
```